# Number of compositions of $n$ into an odd number of part, each of which is at least $3$

Tags: combinatorics

I'm having trouble with the following question:

Let $a_n$ be the number of compositions of $n$ into an odd number of parts, each of which is at least $3$. Prove that
$a_n = [x^n]\frac{x^3-x^4}{1-2x-x^2-x^6}.$

This is what i've done so far:

Let $S=N_{\text{odd}\geq 3}^k$ where $N_{\text{odd}\geq 3}= \{3,5,7,...\}.$
Then we have that

\begin{align}
[x^n]\Phi_S(x) &= [x^n]N_{\text{odd}\geq 3}^k(x) \\
               &= [x^n](N_{\text{odd}\geq 3}(x))^k \:\: \text{by product lemma} \\
               &= [x^n](x^3+x^5+x^7+...)^k \\
               &= [x^n](x^3(1+x^2+x^4+...))^k \\
               &= [x^n](\frac{x^3}{1-x^2})^k \:\: \text{by geometric series}
\end{align}

Since we want an odd number of parts where eacht part is at least $3,$ we obtain 
$(\frac{x^3}{1-x^2})^3 + (\frac{x^3}{1-x^2})^5 + (\frac{x^3}{1-x^2})^7 + ...$

I have no clue on how to continue from here to obtain the expression I want to prove. Maybe again some geometric series? Did I even this the previous part right. 
Hints and/or solutions are very welcome.

Comment: Keep in mind that the number of parts must be odd, but does not need to be at least 3; on the other hand, each part must be at least 3, but does not need to be odd. You seem to be trying to make both quantities be odd numbers 3 or larger.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I read the problem wrong, I must have seen the word "parts" and filled in the rest.  I'm not sure what I was thinking with the rest anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the individual parts are not required to be odd, just at least 3, you should have $[x^n](x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + \cdots)^k$ in your third line.  This  is of course $[x^n](x^3/(1-x))^k$.

Summing over odd $k \ge 1$ gives
$$ \left( x^3 \over 1-x \right)^1 + \left( x^3 \over 1-x \right)^3 + \left( x^3 \over 1-x \right)^5 + \cdots$$

and this is itself a geometric series with common ratio $(x^3/(1-x))^2$; you can get the result you want by doing some algebra.

Comment: (+1) Isn't there a misprint in the OP's denominator of the expected result? (a $-x^2$ instead of $+x^2$)

Comment: Good point! I silently corrected that and shouldn't have.